# What does KEY means in IBM Cloud cli's cloud object store plugin?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload files into my IBM Cloud object store using cli. The command is the following:

> :~ ibmcloud cos object-put --bucket Backup --body Downloads/DRIVING_MIVUE/Normal/F/FILE201217-151749F.MP4
> FAILED
> Mandatory Flag '--key' is missing
> NAME:
> ibmcloud cos object-put - Upload an object to a bucket.
>
> USAGE:
> ibmcloud cos object-put --bucket BUCKET_NAME --key KEY [--body FILE_PATH] [--cache-control CACHING_DIRECTIVES] [--content-disposition DIRECTIVES] [--content-encoding CONTENT_ENCODING] [--content-language LANGUAGE] [--content-length SIZE] [--content-md5 MD5] [--content-type MIME] [--metadata STRUCTURE] [--region REGION] [--output FORMAT] [--json]
>
> OPTIONS:
>
> --bucket BUCKET_NAME                 The name (BUCKET_NAME) of the bucket.
>
> --key KEY                            The KEY of the object.
>
> ...

What does `KEY` mean here?
I tried to provide a string, like below, but I got an error.

> ibmcloud cos object-put --bucket Backup --body Downloads/DRIVING_MIVUE/Normal/F/FILE201217-151749F.MP4 --key FILE201217-151749F
>
> FAILED
> The specified key does not exist.

Comment: on this doc page you can find explanation about the key: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage/getting-started.html&_ga=2.132786057.628522865.1603112762-1893138611.1579124033#gs-add-objects

Answer (score 0):

The object key (or key name) uniquely identifies the object in a bucket. The following are examples of valid object key names:

- 4my-organization
- my.great_photos-2014/jan/myvacation.jpg
- videos/2014/birthday/video1.wmv

For example, when I run the below command

```sh
ibmcloud cos object-put --bucket vmac-code-engine-bucket --region us-geo --key test/package.json --body package.json
```

> The file `package.json` on my machine will be uploaded to the `test`
> folder(directory) of COS bucket `vmac-code-engine-bucket`

Optionally, you can also pass the MAP of metadata to store

```json
{
"file_name": "file_20xxxxxxxxxxxx45.zip",
"label": "texas",
"state": "Texas",
"Date_to": "2019-11-09T16:00:00.000Z",
"Sha256sum": "9e39dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx8ce6b68ede3a47",
"Timestamp": "Thu, 17 Oct 2019 09:22:13 GMT"
}
```

For other parameters, refer the [command documentation here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-cli-plugin-ic-cos-cli#ic-upload-object)

For more information, refer the [documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html)

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I have observed:-

> Key should be Name of the object.

> Body should be file path of the object that needs to be uploaded.